# Set Div inside body to 100% height less body

Tags: html, css

I have created a basic layout following this example:

```
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

With the following CSS Applied:

```
body {
height: 100%;
}

#header {
height: 70px;
}

#content {
height: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

My content tag is 100% of my body tag, resulting in an extra 70px of div height and causing overflow/scroll bars. I want the page to be responsive to the height of the browser but I do not want to set both `div`s inside my body with a `%`, as I need my header to be consistently 70px. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What should happen when the content of `#content` exceeds the element height (overflow)? Should scollbars appear? Should the header always be visible, when scrolling (depends on the previous question)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use fixed positioning:

```css
#header, #content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#header {
  top: 0;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}
#content {
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS's `calc()`:

```
#content{
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  display: block;
}
```

This will minus 70px from the current screen height

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/utv69qze/

you can use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) also set you `html` `height` to `100%`

```
#content {
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```